# Unable to see most metrics in Cassandra 3.3

Tags: cassandra, metrics, codahale-metrics

I set up metrics+graphite+grafana monitoring with Cassandra 2.2. After upgrading to Cassandra 3.3, I'm no longer able to see JVM metrics nor anything in org.apache.cassandra.ColumnFamily.*. My metrics.yaml file is below:

```
graphite:
- period: 30
  timeunit: 'SECONDS'
  prefix: 'cassandra-%%hostid%%'
  hosts:
  - host: '%%graphite_host%%'
    port: %%graphite_port%%
  predicate:
    color: "white"
    useQualifiedName: true
    patterns:
    - ".*"
```

Comment: Where did you put your graphite-metrics jar and what version did you use please? My jar is located in the lib dir and my graphite yaml is located in the conf directory. I struggle setting it up. Get this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.graphite.GraphiteSender.

Answer (score 1):

They were moved into `org.apache.cassandra.Tables.*` for consistency with CQL nomenclature.